# Is there a way to make rfind() case insensitive?

Tags: python, find, case-insensitive

I'm parsing a bunch of files for specific urls..

The subdirectory can be upper-case, lower-case or camel-case in these:

```
search = "http://website.com/content/" + subdirectory + "/?"
begin = contents.rfind(search)
```

It would be great for this to work regardless of the case of the sub-directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
begin = contents.lower().rfind(search.lower())
```